# Rails: Access record instance inside of serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt some JSON data with a custom column serializer in rails. Because the encryption needs to be reversible I am using AES 256 CBC with a cipher key and initialization vector (IV).

I want the key and iv to be unique to each record which has instance methods to provide those two values. The problem I'm having right now is that I can't access the record instance inside of the serializer/coder so I'm not sure how to pass those values to it.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
class MyModel
  serialize :keys, EncryptedJSON

  def data_encryption_key
    Digest::SHA2.new(256).hexdigest("#{user.id}:#{user.created_at.utc.to_i}:#{ENV["SOME_SECRECT_KEY_VALUE"]}")
  end

  def data_encryption_iv
    Digest::SHA2.new(256).hexdigest(user.created_at.utc.to_i)
  end
end

class EncryptedJSON
  require 'openssl'

  # decode, decrypt and convert to json
  def self.load(encrypted)
    return if encrypted.nil?

    decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(256, :CBC)

    decipher.decrypt

    # I want this to use: record.data_encryption_key()
    decipher.key = Digest::SHA2.new(256).hexdigest("123") 

    # I want this to use: record.data_encryption_iv()
    decipher.iv = Digest::SHA2.new(256).hexdigest("123") 

    encrypted = Base64.decode64(encrypted)
    decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted) + decipher.final

    JSON.parse(decrypted)
  end

  # convert to string, encrypt and encode
  def self.dump(data)
    return if data.nil?

    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(256, :CBC)

    cipher.encrypt

    # I want this to use: record.data_encryption_key()
    cipher.key = Digest::SHA2.new(256).hexdigest("123")

    # I want this to use: record.data_encryption_iv()
    cipher.iv = Digest::SHA2.new(256).hexdigest("123") 

    encrypted = cipher.update(data.to_s) + cipher.final

    Base64.encode64(encrypted)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately since serialize is a class method, there is no way to pass a reference to an instance.  In order to do what you need to do, you are going to have to manually handle serialization and deserialization by overwriting the getter and setter methods for keys.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def keys=(json)
    write_attribute(:keys, EncryptedJSON.dump(json, self))
  end

  def keys
    EncryptedJSON.load(read_attribute(:keys), self)
  end
end
```